# show element while promise is beging fulled, hide when complete

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some javascript code in vuejs where i want to show and hide an element as the promise is returning the response. Once that is complete, i want it to hide. I already have the success:resolve in it, just not sure how to trigger the show/hide of the element.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
  food:[],
  
  },
  mounted:function(){
  this.getCode();
  },
  methods: {
    methods:{
        async getCode() {

        this.food = await Promise.all(this.food.map(async food => {
           food.box = await this.request('GET',`https://example.com/${food.Identifier}/content/voc`)

            return food
            
        }))
   
      },

       request(type, url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          $.ajax({
            url,
            type,
            headers: {
              accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: resolve,
            fail: reject
          })
        })
      },
 
  }
})
```

```css
 #spin {
                border: 20px solid yellow;
                border-top: 20px solid;
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                margin: auto;
            }

            @keyframes spin {
                0% {
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }

                100% {
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<h2>Promise:</h2>
 
 <div id="app">
 <div id ="spin"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set a variable (`isLoading`) before and after your request and use `v-if` directive to show/hide the element:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    food:[],
    isLoading: false,
  },
  mounted:function(){
    this.getCode();
  },
  methods: {
    async getCode() {
        this.isLoading = true
        this.food = await Promise.all(this.food.map(async food => {
           food.box = await this.request('GET',`https://example.com/${food.Identifier}/content/voc`)

            return food
            
        }))
        this.isLoading = false
    },

    request(type, url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          $.ajax({
            url,
            type,
            headers: {
              accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: resolve,
            fail: reject
          })
        })
    },
 
  }
})
```

```css
#spin {
                border: 20px solid yellow;
                border-top: 20px solid;
                border-radius: 50%;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
                margin: auto;
            }

            @keyframes spin {
                0% {
                    transform: rotate(0deg);
                }

                100% {
                    transform: rotate(360deg);
                }
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<h2>Promise:</h2>
 
 <div id="app">
 <div id ="spin" v-if="isLoading"></div>

</div>
```